# Regex get the word after match

Tags: regex

I have a log file.
In the log file I have a lot of lines and each line contain something like this:

```
<h4>adi</h4><small>08/02/2015 11:14:16</small>
```

The name between `h4` tag different in every line also the time

I want to catch, using regex the time and the date in the line where I can find the name "adi", and as I said, there is only one line contains the name "adi".

Btw - the log is html.

Comment: What language are you using? And why do you have these commas within the tags?

Comment: Well that's a very strange format. What's with all the commas? Also you've said "using regex" but I see no reason why regex should be the preferred way to do this. Personally I'd strip the commas first then use an XML parser (to make sure it will stay safe with XML encoded entities, for example).

Comment: I have the commas -only in the question  and not in the log- because if I post it with commas the website act like I'm using html in my question

Comment: You can try the following regex, assuming the date always appear within `<small>` tags: `adi.*<small>(.*)</small>`. Depending on the language you're using, I advise you to use a parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

This matches your target input:

```
(?<=^<h4>adi</h4><small>)[^<]+
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/nUHnhXl9tq).

Comment: `<h4>Bradi</h4><small>08/02/2015 11:14:16</small>`

Comment: @Dave even though your comment is not possible (question says `adi` is unique in the file), it's a good point for the general case, so I have tightened up the regex to anchor to start of line.

Comment: Well the OP said only one "contains the name adi". I'd argue that "Bradi" does *not* contain the name "adi", only the letters "adi". But then it feels like this has just become a language lawyer question on the English language... Anyway better to be correct. Now I move on to `<h4 class="myheader">&#97;di</h4> <small>08/02/2015 11:14:16</small>`

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**:Proceed with caution. Regex is not supposed to be used for HTML parsing.Use a parser instead!

```
(?<=adi</h4>\s*<small>)[^<]+
```